# Python Mock with `from X import y`

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-mock

I am trying to use Python's `mock` library in my unit testing but I am seeing inconsistent results depending on how I import the target that I am trying to patch. I would expect that both of these print statements should return `False` but it appears that only the second statement returns `False`:

```
from requests import get
import requests

with mock.patch('requests.get') as get_mock:
    get_mock.return_value.ok = False
    print get('http://asdf.com').ok
    print requests.get('http://asdf.com').ok
```

Comment: Are you still interested?

Comment: About this question... I've not received any feedback on my answer. There are something that is not clear?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) `unittest.mock` documentation you should pay some attention about what you patch.

Use

```
from requests import get
```

create a local reference (a copy) of the original method. By

```
with mock.patch('requests.get') as get_mock:
```

you patch just the reference in `requests` module that give to you so called *inconsistent results* because the local reference created by `from` sentence remain untouched.

The local reference can be patched by `patch.object(get)` or `patch('__main__.get')`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who came over to look for mocking a module that does `from requests import get`

you can mock this by using `your_module.get`