# Fudge: @patch not working when from X import Y'ing instead of import X?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-import, fudge

I came across a strange bahviour of the `patch` decorator in Fudge 1.0.3. It does not patch the module when importing classes via

```
from <module> import <class>
```

but works fine when importing

```
import <module>
```

with the corresponding code adaption.

Here's a minimalized setup:

**mdle.py**:

```
class Klaas(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # easyest way to signal this class has been instantiated accidently
        raise Exception(">:[")
```

**some.py** (test not working):

```
from mdle import Klaas()
def instantiate():
    instance = Klaas()
```

**some.py** (test working):

```
import mdle
def instantiate():
    instance = mdle.Klaas()
```

**some_test.py**:

```
import unittest
import fudge

import some

class SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @fudge.patch("mdle.Klaas")
    def test_somethingb(self, Klaas_mock):
        klaas_inst = (Klaas_mock.expects_call()
                            .returns_fake())


        # Receiving the exception
        some.instantiate()
```

Should I patch in a different way? Is this a limitation of Fudge, or a bug?

Comment: Note that `@fudge.patch("mdle.Klass")` is only going to work if *that's the name being used*. If you `from mdle import Klass`, switch the patch target to `"Klass"`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately the [documentation](http://farmdev.com/projects/fudge/api/fudge.html#fudge.patch) is not quite clear about that: `A test decorator that patches importable names with fakes`. You should make an answer, if you like.

Comment: I don't know `fudge` at all but I can guess it looks like to `unittest.mock.patch` behavior. Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546137/python-mock-with-from-x-import-y/28570892#28570892

Answer (score 2):

You have to patch the name where the object is being *referenced*, not where it's being defined.

Remember modules are just objects with a dict of names pointing to other objects (a class is an object too). The same object can have multiple (possibly identical) names in different modules. Patching makes a name temporarily point to a `Fake` rather than to the original object.

I assume in your first (not working) `some.py` module you meant:

```
from mdle import Klass
```

That creates a name `some.Klass` that gets used in that module. The name happens to match the name in `mdle` by default, but you actually have two names pointing to the same class object. It's the name in `some` you need to patch if you want to use a fake instead, because that's the name used to reference the class in the module under test.

Your test patches `mdle.Klass` which is not the name used in `some`, so your code still picks up the real class object using its own unpatched name. You need to patch `some.Klass` instead in this case.

In your second (working) `some.py` you import the whole `mdle` module and reference the class using the name in that module. That's why patching `mdle.Klass` works in that case, you're patching the name that's being used.

Comment: Thanks for your (late) response. It makes sense now. "I assume ... you meant" - Yes, I meant `from mdle import Klass` (probably typed the reduced example to simplify the example).